# Data cardinality is ambguous: Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am attempting to train a sequential model using Keras, however, I encountered an error when attempting to provide input into the NN. The NN has 2 layers, with 250 hidden nodes.

Specifically, the model trains based on the initial data shape of (14768,1) to the output shape of (5997, 1). This is predominantly achieved through the lines containing `np.reshape`. Weirdly enough, when the input and outputs are swapped, the model trains normally. In addition, if the `validation_split=0.1` attribute is removed, then the program fails for similar reasons.

As such, it appears to me that the NN fails when

1. the input shape is larger than the output shape? or
2. when no `validation_split` is specified?

It is important that I maintain the intial 14768 input features as they are required for predicting the 5997 output features. I have tried multiple related solutions which involve converting the input and output type to numpy.ndarray however they have provided no progress in resolving the issue.

```
...
Nodes = [250, 250]
# train here is a matrix of shape (5997, 149), where there are 149 columns for each individual, and 5997 features to be predicted
train_sample=np.reshape(train[:,0], (-1, 1))
# train_sample.shape = (5997,1)

# feature_train here is a matrix of shape (14768, 149), where there are 149 columns for each individual, and 14768 features to be learned
feature_sample=np.reshape(feature_train[:,0], (-1, 1))
# feature_sample.shape = (14768,1)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=Nodes[0], activation='elu', input_dim=feature_sample.shape[1]))

if len(Nodes) > 1:
    for i in range(len(Nodes) - 1):
        model.add(Dense(units=Nodes[i + 1], activation='elu'))

model.add(Dense(units=train_sample.shape[1], activation='elu'))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None,decay=0.01)
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error,
                  optimizer=adam,
                  metrics=['accuracy'], )

model.summary()
# _________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
# dense (Dense)                (None, 250)               500       
# _________________________________________________________________
# dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 250)               62750     
# _________________________________________________________________
# dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 251       
# =================================================================

for i in range(5):  
    seqModel = model.fit(feature_sample, train_sample, epochs=100, batch_size=50, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)
# NOTE: 13291 here is 90% of 14768, the original input with the validation_split removed
# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
#   x sizes: 13291
#   y sizes: 5997
# Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

How to proceed?

Comment: How many training examples do you have? For 1 training example, what is the `shape` of  `x`, and what is the shape of `y` ?

Comment: @AndrzejO there are a total of 149 training individuals, where X (feature_sample) is a single individual column (14768, 1) of the training matrix (14768, 149). Similarly, Y (train_sample) is a the predicted state of the same paired individual (5997, 1) sliced similarly from the predicted output matrix (5997, 149). Does this clarify the training?